# jQuery validate plugin - not hiding errorContainer

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've learning how to use the jQuery validate plugin. I've got a table with some form fields that I need to validate. Ideally, I want every row to have an additional row underneath it specifically for displaying the error message corresponding to it. Naturally, I want these error message rows to be hidden apart from when they need to display the error message.

The docs for the plugin says:

> The elements given as the errorContainer are all shown and hidden when errors occur. But the error labels themselve are added to the element(s) given as errorLabelContainer

so I assumed that if I added an "errorRow" class to every one of the rows that I want to display the errors and declared those rows to be errorContainers then they would be hidden. This isn't working for me and I don't know why.

Here's some simplified code:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="appLabelColumn">
        <label>First name:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="appValueColumn">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="errorRow">
    <td class="appLabelColumn">
        <label>Error:</label>
    </td>
    <td class="appValueColumn">

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('#myform').validate({
            rules: {
                firstName: "required"
            },
            message: {
                firstName: "Please enter your first name."
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
            },
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorRow .appValueColumn",
            errorContainer: "#errorRow, #errorRow td"
});
```

any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: I think it's this -> errorContainer: "#errorRow, #errorRow td" doing your error it's places two error in the same time.
I'm not so sure about it, can you try and if it's correct submit the whole code i would really appreciate it.

Comment: no, I've tried just the errorContainer: #errorRow on it's own and it didn't work, unfortunately. Also the docs show that more than one box can be declared an errorContainer, although specifying the td and it's parent is probably overkill anyway.

Comment: This works fine for me on Firefox if `#errorRow` is initially hidden. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gQFeu/).

Comment: @Frederic Right. That works for me now. I tried hiding it earlier as well. I must have altered something else since. I thought the plugin is meant to hide the errorContainers by default. I must understand the plugin code. Which means I'm going to have to improve my JavaScript a lot. Thanks for the help. Also thanks for showing me JSFiddle looks very useful. :)

Comment: @Joe, you're welcome, and it's a very good idea to dig into plugin code in order to learn what you need. That said, you can figure a lot of things out from the documentation alone by following a simple rule: *a feature only exists if it is documented*. Does the documentation for `errorContainer` mention the plugin hides the container when `validate()` is called? If not, then that feature doesn't exist, and you should not assume it does :)